# Getting list of results from etags.el

Tags: emacs, elisp, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm generating a tags file (in emacs format) using exuberant ctags, I pass this additional flag:

```
--regex-PHP=/do\_action\(\ '([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)'/\1/a,actions/
```

Which successfully captures what I want, the issue is I want to use emacs lisp to return all tags marked as "a" in the form of a list - or I'll even settle for just matching a regular expression of do_action.

Unfortunately, it seems everything in etags.el is geared towards interactive usage, `find-tag-in-order` was the only non-interactive way I could think to do it, but my code returns an error message regardless of whether or not anything is matching:

```
(find-tag-in-order
 "test_string"
 find-tag-regexp-search-function
 find-tag-regexp-tag-order
 find-tag-regexp-next-line-after-failure-p
 "matching"
 t)
```

While doing an interactive M-x find-tag test_string will bring me to the file and point in which it's defined.

The ideal usage would be something like:
`(tags-of-type "a")` or `(tags-matching "do_action")`. Though I understand the *name* of the tag is what's matched in the parenthesized group of my regular expression.

Any ideas?

**Update:**
Though this does not solve the issue of getting tags in the form of an emacs lisp list, I realize that with the `--PHP-kinds` parameter it will be possible to maintain multiple tags files for each type.

In this method, the approach (while not working) would be something like this:

```
(let ((tags-table-list '("tag-file-1")))
  (tags-search "specific-to-tag-file-1"))
```

Comment: Interactive functions can be called just like any other function, so is there a problem with calling `(find-tag test_string)` from your code?

Comment: Yes - calling that function from elisp also acts interactively instead of returning matching tags as strings.

Comment: You might look at the [etags-select](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EtagsSelect) library for an example implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want, I think, is `(tags-completion-table)`.  It returns an obarray of symbols that are entries in the current TAGS tables.

In any case, depending on just what it is that you are after, I think function `tags-completion-table` and its cache variable of the same name are the place to start.  Both are defined in library `etags.el`.

(If you need a list of strings instead of an obarray of symbols, just use `mapatoms` and `symbol-name`.)

Comment: I had to use ```mapcar``` actually, but it did work. Any thought on using multiple tags files since etags won't separate type? (re my last code snippet in original question)

Comment: You should use `mapatoms`, not `mapcar`, to iterate over an obarray. Dunno what your last question means (e.g., "won't separate type"?).

Comment: If I were to "visit" multiple tags files, meaning my ```(tags-completion-table)``` would be a list of all tags throughout all files, is there a way to narrow them down to those within a single tags file?

Also ```(mapcar 'symbol-name (tags-completion-table))``` returns a list of strings, while the same using ```mapatoms``` returns nil.

Comment: You don't use `mapatoms` for its result.  You use it only for its side effect (see the doc string).  You would bind a local var to () and then push symbol names to it with `mapatoms`.  Then you would use the var's value (e.g. return it).  An obarray is not an ordinary vector.  `See (elisp) Creating Symbols`, in particular this part (see next comment):

Comment: "In Emacs Lisp, an obarray is actually a vector.  Each element of the
vector is a bucket; its value is either an interned symbol whose name
hashes to that bucket, or 0 if the bucket is empty.  Each interned
symbol has an internal link (invisible to the user) to the next symbol
in the bucket.  ***Because these links are invisible, there is no way to
find all the symbols in an obarray except using `mapatoms'*** (below).
The order of symbols in a bucket is not significant."

Comment: See `visit-tags-table`, `visit-tags-table-buffer`, and `tags-file-name`.